# Observablecollection updates multiple items when updating a property

Tags: c#, wpf

When I update a property from my `ObservableCollection` I notice a strange behavior because multiple items within my collection are getting updated with the same value. Is this a normal behavior? The binding in XAML is normal and working so no issue there, or am i doing something wrong. My simple class bound to `ObservableCollection` in a `ListView.Just` want to know if i am missing something.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged {

   private string _name;
   public string Name {
    get{ return _name;}
    set{ _name=value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
  }

private string _Age {
    get{ return _age;}
    set{ _age=value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("Age");
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? The xaml and your observable collection and where you're adding items to it

Comment: im sorry guys im corrently writting on a guest laptop. Adding items, duplicating and removing everything works fine. just when i click on the listview and getting the current item to update the above item gets the same values like the updated one. im not asking for bug fixes just for a idea :)

Comment: And we are just asking for a complete problem statement

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have multiple references to the same instance in your list. So all items for that same instance would logically update. Hard to know with certainty without the code, though.

Comment: thanks for your answer sorry for the little code :) . Makes sense should i add a unique identifier to make the references unique ? or am i wrong

Comment: It's not about identifiers, the instances are unique, you just need to make sure not to add the same instance twice, but add a new one instead.

Comment: ok this makes sense so i basicly check if the collection contains the reference already